# Why are there discrepancies between build.phonegap.com and console build

Tags: android, cordova, cloud

Right so i know that PhoneGap originates in the Apache Cordova project.
This becomes apparent when one looks at the PhoneGap documentation.

When I build a PhoneGap app through the console `phonegap build android` I get an Apk with one type of icons, no startup splash and overall better performance.

If i go through http://build.phonegap.com I get a very different app. Splash-screen, wrong permissions and a different icon-set.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was myself wondering why for a phonegap local project the changes in www/res folder were not reported in the platforms folders. So here are my conclusions...

Cordova projects are always local projects. When you create a cordova project (cordova create ...), there are no icons and no splash added in the project.

icons for a specific platform are added when you add that platform to the project : cordova platform add android will add the cordova icon for each dpi in platforms/android/res and not add any splash. It's then up to the developper to put icons and splash in the platforms folders and customize the specific platform configuration files.

That makes sense because files resolutions for icons and splash are quite different for android, windows phone or ios and someone doing a project only for android will not want to provide images in a resolution that will only be necessary for an ios build.

Most of the phonegap commands are just a copy of cordova commands, some of them are customised to allow specific needs for phonegap build.

So `phonegap create` creates a project with a config.xml following a different schema than the one of config.xml in cordova.xml

**cordova:**

```
<widget id="com.test.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

**Phonegap:**

```
<widget id="com.test.test" version="1.4.7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

This allows for configuration of splashscreens, icons, plugins with the `<gap: />` nodes.

The config.xml file created by `phonegap create` contains configuration for a splash screen and an icon stored in www/res. And `phonegap create` also creates the www/res folder with the phonegap logo (so different from the cordova logo) as default splash and icon.

Where things start to be puzzling is that each `phonegap platform add` are unmodified copies of the corresponding `cordova platform add` commands and therefore do not take in account phonegap specificities.

`phonegap create` command will download platform icons instead of using the ones already in www/res and `phonegap build` command will not report changes in www/res to the platforms bitmaps.

I think it would be better (or at least less confusing) if `phonegap create` and `phonegap build` commands were modified to use the same structure as phonegap build project, but maybe it would be too much maintenance for phonegap teams at each new release.